# MATLAB populating a vector with a date number

Tags: matlab

I have a vector called dateNum_vec that I wish to populate with a date but as a date number. I want the vector contain the same amount of elements as the matrix "MyMatrix" 3rd column? How do I do this? I currently have the line below,

```
datenum_vec = [1 : length(MyMatrix,3)] = datenum(workday)
```

I have found the answer, please see below. However I would like to know how to do this all in one line.

```
datenum_vec = (1 : length(tdata))';
datenum_vec(:) = datenum(workday);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `workday` contains your date vectors you should be able to use `datenum_vec = datenum(workday(1:size(MyMatrix,1)))`
if I am not mistaken

you should give the (example)dimensions and contents if you ask questions like this